# springboot app on azure app service stops right after start

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I have a spring boot rest application on azure app service. Anytime I deploy an application with **azure DevOps pipeline** or with **azure-webapp-maven-plugin** directly, the deployment works successfully as I can see all the uploaded files in **site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT** from the *Kudu Debug Console*. When I try to hit any endpoint or even the application URL, it returns a 404(Not Found error).
I pulled up the logs and this is what I find.

```
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:31,644 org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver logKeyFound - - Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with value of type String
[INFO] 2020-05-24 10:45:31,660 com.company.product.core.MainApplication logStarted - - Started MainApplication in 37.424 seconds (JVM running for 65.143)
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,347 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext doClose - - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@60d5a711, started on Sun May 24 10:44:58 GMT 2020
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,378 org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver logKeyFound - - Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with value of type String
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,456 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop - - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,456 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor lambda$doStop$2 - - Bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' completed its stop procedure
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,456 org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter destroy - - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[DEBUG] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,456 org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter unregisterBeans - - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
[INFO] 2020-05-24 10:45:32,456 org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor shutdown - - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

The application shuts down right after it's initialized. It looks to me as if the app service is sending a shutdown command to the spring boot application. 
Can anybody help with this? I'm pressed on time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without seeing the code. Does your app run and proceed requests if started on local mashine?

Comment: Yes please, it runs on my local machine

Comment: Can you try packing the SpringBoot app as a JAR (which has embedded Tomcat). Name it app.jar and place it under D:\home\site\wwwroot folder of the WebApp. You can upload it directly via the Kudu site. Remove web.config, if any.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we deploy spring boot app to azure web app by using jar file. Here are the steps:

1.Go to your webapp in the portal->Configuration->check the Java container. We will use Java SE instead of Tomcat.

[image]

2.Go to your webapp in the portal->Advanced Tools->Debug console->Cmd. Put your jar file under wwwroot folder. Need to name it as app.jar.

3.The result

[image]

[image]